# Create an extension thay works with social media?

Tags: facebook, media, privacy

I'm a student in second year of computer ingeneering school and in one of my classes we were tasked to think of a novel idea to promote the wellbeing of people online. Some students are working on promoting better eating or exercising or peomoting spending less time on social media, etc. I'm thinking of something but I just wanted if you know whether it is feasible or not with the existing privacy laws and the restrictions that social media has for developers.

My idea: promising more privacy-aware behavior. Basically, I want to be able to detect when the user is writing something in a comment or status update (kinda like how grammar lyrics works by accessing text in real time) and detect if the user is sharing something sensitive. The objective is to pop a notification when such a thing happens and try to discourage users feom sharing the post before they click "post" or "share".

I tried a dummy example on a simulated environment (I used a natural language processing API that a classmate developed previously) but I'm hesitant on what would happen if I attempt this as a Chrome extention, for example, that would work simultaneously with facebook. Does Facebook even allows developers (after getting permission from users of course) to track what they are writing and to send them notifications? Do privacy laws in the US forbid me from doing this?

I asked my teacher some questions but she told me that she isn't an expert in privacy and cannot give me a definitive answer.

So, I would greatly appreciate it if I receive responses from people who have knowledge in the field. If some parts of this are not doable, or if it's completely unrealistic, please let me know so that I can choose another project. Il

Thank you so much.

I tried a dummy example on a simulated social media environment but I'm struggling to fo it as an extension